# List of Arduino board preprocessor #defines

Tags: ide, c-preprocessor

When one selects a board within Arduino IDE, a preprocessor definition is added to one of the behind-the-scenes files.

After a lot of hunting and some good fortune I found that the format of this definition is:

```
#define ARDUINO_<PROCESSOR-DESCRIPTOR>_<BOARDNAME>
```

Some are easy to guess (`ARDUINO_AVR_UNO`, for example), but others are less so. The Pro Micro has '16' or '8' appended to the definition depending on the speed. I do not know if the definition is different for 5V or 3.3V. I haven't managed to guess the definition for the Mega2560, but it isn't anything obvious.

**Question 1**: Is there a list in existence of the possible definitions?

**Question 2**: Is there any distinction, as far as compilation and preprocessor involvement is concerned, between *BoardX*-5V and *BoardX*-3.3V, and how is this distinction defined?

Comment: What do you need it for? It would probably be more useful to differentiate between processors (e.g. ATMega328), instead of boards.

Comment: I have a multi-node project that uses an Uno, a Leonardo and a <collective noun> of Pro Minis. The code is nearly identical for the three versions but to ease debugging I want to be able to upload (or at least compile from) the same code for everything.

Comment: Switch on File>Preferences>Compile Verbose. Then build/verify and inspect the output. You will see the -D defines that are passed to the compiler. This makes it easy to determine the difference between your boards.

Comment: Grep did not work for me as shown. Found the path by looking at the verbose compiler output. I discovered the SparkFun boards.txt file on my computer was located here:
C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Arduino15\staging\packages\sparkfunboards.1.1.10.tar\avr-1.1.10\boards.txt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The list of board symbols can be generated by this shell command:

```
$ grep board= boards.txt | cut -f2 -d= | sort -u
AVR_ADK
AVR_BT
AVR_DUEMILANOVE
AVR_ESPLORA
AVR_ETHERNET
AVR_FIO
AVR_GEMMA
AVR_LEONARDO
AVR_LILYPAD
AVR_LILYPAD_USB
AVR_MEGA
AVR_MEGA2560
AVR_MICRO
AVR_MINI
AVR_NANO
AVR_NG
AVR_PRO
AVR_ROBOT_CONTROL
AVR_ROBOT_MOTOR
AVR_UNO
AVR_YUN
```

The boards are defined by the "build.board" property in the [boards.txt](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt) file.

```
mini.build.board=AVR_MINI
```

This property is used by the build [recipe](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt#L52) together with ARDUINO_-prefix.

```
-DARDUINO_{build.board}
```

Cheers!

Comment: +1, thank you for that list. It's a shame it doesn't spit out the dual-speed versions to remove any doubt, but this answers the question more than well enough.

Comment: The board property is the same for both versions of pro-mini while not for mega. Maybe boards.txt should be updated with distinctive names for the pro-mini variants, e.g. AVR_MINI_16MHZ, AVR_MINI_8MHZ.

Comment: For those looking - I was trying to find the define for a NodeMCU ESP8266 - so based on the info in this answer, it is ARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU

Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

Mikael has the right answer, but there are multiple boards.txt files depending on the installed boards with board manager,
modifying the command to:

```
grep board= `find . -name boards.txt` | cut -f2 -d= | sort -u
```

and running it from your base Arduino directory collects the whole set.

Comment: Adding detail to Bill's answer adding to Mikael's: The packages you download through the Board Manager reside in (as of 1.8.9 and many revs prior):
> linux: /home/(your login)/.arduino15 You can also run Bill's one line script in your Arduino installation folder, to get the 'builtin' boards.

Answer (score 3):

The first blank is the *platform*. This is "AVR" for AVRs, "SAM" for SAM-based Arduinos, etc. This is derived from the platform directory containing the core.

The second blank is the *board*. This comes from the entry in `boards.txt` in the core itself, and is the identifier before the first period.

There is no difference between compilation processes with regards to voltages; any speed difference is given in `F_CPU` and the board itself should not be checked for this.

So there is no definitive list, since the list is of arbitrary size due to its source.

Comment: This is true only when boards.txt doesn't define a `build.board` value and one is automatically generated by the Arduino IDE.