# ESP32 on Arduino IDE: Identify the board type in code (preprocessor macro)

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, compile

I have read the answers on [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/arduino-how-to-get-the-board-type-in-code), but they do not seem to be providing a solution for ESP32 boards.

Is there a way to get the .name that is used from the boards.txt without modifying the platform.txt?

for example for uno there is uno.name=Arduino Uno
for esp32 esp32wrover.name=ESP32 Wrover Module

For ESP32 I can only find .name having the specific board name

This is a sample of the first 2 boards defined in boards.txt for esp332

```
menu.UploadSpeed=Upload Speed
menu.CPUFreq=CPU Frequency
menu.FlashFreq=Flash Frequency
menu.FlashMode=Flash Mode
menu.FlashSize=Flash Size
menu.PartitionScheme=Partition Scheme
menu.DebugLevel=Core Debug Level
menu.PSRAM=PSRAM
menu.Revision=Board Revision

##############################################################
### DO NOT PUT BOARDS ABOVE THE OFFICIAL ESPRESSIF BOARDS! ###
##############################################################

esp32.name=ESP32 Dev Module

esp32.upload.tool=esptool_py
esp32.upload.maximum_size=1310720
esp32.upload.maximum_data_size=327680
esp32.upload.wait_for_upload_port=true

esp32.serial.disableDTR=true
esp32.serial.disableRTS=true

esp32.build.mcu=esp32
esp32.build.core=esp32
esp32.build.variant=esp32
esp32.build.board=ESP32_DEV

esp32.build.f_cpu=240000000L
esp32.build.flash_size=4MB
esp32.build.flash_freq=40m
esp32.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32.build.boot=dio
esp32.build.partitions=default
esp32.build.defines=

esp32.menu.PSRAM.disabled=Disabled
esp32.menu.PSRAM.disabled.build.defines=
esp32.menu.PSRAM.enabled=Enabled
esp32.menu.PSRAM.enabled.build.defines=-DBOARD_HAS_PSRAM -mfix-esp32-psram-cache-issue

esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default=Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default.build.partitions=default
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.defaultffat=Default 4MB with ffat (1.2MB APP/1.5MB FATFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.defaultffat.build.partitions=default_ffat
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default_8MB=8M Flash (3MB APP/1.5MB FAT)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default_8MB.build.partitions=default_8MB
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.default_8MB.upload.maximum_size=3342336
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.minimal=Minimal (1.3MB APP/700KB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.minimal.build.partitions=minimal
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota=No OTA (2MB APP/2MB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota.build.partitions=no_ota
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota.upload.maximum_size=2097152
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g=No OTA (1MB APP/3MB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g.build.partitions=noota_3g
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g.upload.maximum_size=1048576
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat=No OTA (2MB APP/2MB FATFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat.build.partitions=noota_ffat
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat.upload.maximum_size=2097152
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat=No OTA (1MB APP/3MB FATFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat.build.partitions=noota_3gffat
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat.upload.maximum_size=1048576
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app=Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.build.partitions=huge_app
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.upload.maximum_size=3145728
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs=Minimal SPIFFS (1.9MB APP with OTA/190KB SPIFFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs.build.partitions=min_spiffs
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs.upload.maximum_size=1966080
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.fatflash=16M Flash (2MB APP/12.5MB FAT)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.fatflash.build.partitions=ffat
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.fatflash.upload.maximum_size=2097152
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.app3M_fat9M_16MB=16M Flash (3MB APP/9MB FATFS)
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.app3M_fat9M_16MB.build.partitions=app3M_fat9M_16MB
esp32.menu.PartitionScheme.app3M_fat9M_16MB.upload.maximum_size=3145728

esp32.menu.CPUFreq.240=240MHz (WiFi/BT)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.240.build.f_cpu=240000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.160=160MHz (WiFi/BT)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.160.build.f_cpu=160000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.80=80MHz (WiFi/BT)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.80.build.f_cpu=80000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.40=40MHz (40MHz XTAL)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.40.build.f_cpu=40000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.26=26MHz (26MHz XTAL)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.26.build.f_cpu=26000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.20=20MHz (40MHz XTAL)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.20.build.f_cpu=20000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.13=13MHz (26MHz XTAL)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.13.build.f_cpu=13000000L
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.10=10MHz (40MHz XTAL)
esp32.menu.CPUFreq.10.build.f_cpu=10000000L

esp32.menu.FlashMode.qio=QIO
esp32.menu.FlashMode.qio.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32.menu.FlashMode.qio.build.boot=qio
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dio=DIO
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dio.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dio.build.boot=dio
esp32.menu.FlashMode.qout=QOUT
esp32.menu.FlashMode.qout.build.flash_mode=dout
esp32.menu.FlashMode.qout.build.boot=qout
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dout=DOUT
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dout.build.flash_mode=dout
esp32.menu.FlashMode.dout.build.boot=dout

esp32.menu.FlashFreq.80=80MHz
esp32.menu.FlashFreq.80.build.flash_freq=80m
esp32.menu.FlashFreq.40=40MHz
esp32.menu.FlashFreq.40.build.flash_freq=40m

esp32.menu.FlashSize.4M=4MB (32Mb)
esp32.menu.FlashSize.4M.build.flash_size=4MB
esp32.menu.FlashSize.8M=8MB (64Mb)
esp32.menu.FlashSize.8M.build.flash_size=8MB
esp32.menu.FlashSize.8M.build.partitions=default_8MB
esp32.menu.FlashSize.2M=2MB (16Mb)
esp32.menu.FlashSize.2M.build.flash_size=2MB
esp32.menu.FlashSize.2M.build.partitions=minimal
esp32.menu.FlashSize.16M=16MB (128Mb)
esp32.menu.FlashSize.16M.build.flash_size=16MB

esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.921600=921600
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.921600.upload.speed=921600
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.115200=115200
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.115200.upload.speed=115200
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.256000.windows=256000
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.256000.upload.speed=256000
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.230400.windows.upload.speed=256000
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.230400=230400
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.230400.upload.speed=230400
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.linux=460800
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.macosx=460800
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.upload.speed=460800
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.512000.windows=512000
esp32.menu.UploadSpeed.512000.upload.speed=512000

esp32.menu.DebugLevel.none=None
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.none.build.code_debug=0
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.error=Error
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.error.build.code_debug=1
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.warn=Warn
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.warn.build.code_debug=2
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.info=Info
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.info.build.code_debug=3
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.debug=Debug
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.debug.build.code_debug=4
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.verbose=Verbose
esp32.menu.DebugLevel.verbose.build.code_debug=5

##############################################################

esp32wrover.name=ESP32 Wrover Module

esp32wrover.upload.tool=esptool_py
esp32wrover.upload.maximum_size=1310720
esp32wrover.upload.maximum_data_size=327680
esp32wrover.upload.wait_for_upload_port=true

esp32wrover.serial.disableDTR=true
esp32wrover.serial.disableRTS=true

esp32wrover.build.mcu=esp32
esp32wrover.build.core=esp32
esp32wrover.build.variant=esp32
esp32wrover.build.board=ESP32_DEV

esp32wrover.build.f_cpu=240000000L
esp32wrover.build.flash_size=4MB
esp32wrover.build.flash_freq=40m
esp32wrover.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32wrover.build.boot=dio
esp32wrover.build.partitions=default
esp32wrover.build.defines=-DBOARD_HAS_PSRAM -mfix-esp32-psram-cache-issue

esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.default=Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.default.build.partitions=default
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.defaultffat=Default 4MB with ffat (1.2MB APP/1.5MB FATFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.defaultffat.build.partitions=default_ffat
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.default_8MB=8M Flash (3MB APP/1.5MB FAT)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.default_8MB.build.partitions=default_8MB
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.minimal=Minimal (1.3MB APP/700KB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.minimal.build.partitions=minimal
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota=No OTA (2MB APP/2MB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota.build.partitions=no_ota
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.no_ota.upload.maximum_size=2097152
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g=No OTA (1MB APP/3MB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g.build.partitions=noota_3g
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3g.upload.maximum_size=1048576
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat=No OTA (2MB APP/2MB FATFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat.build.partitions=noota_ffat
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_ffat.upload.maximum_size=2097152
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat=No OTA (1MB APP/3MB FATFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat.build.partitions=noota_3gffat
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.noota_3gffat.upload.maximum_size=1048576
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app=Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.build.partitions=huge_app
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.upload.maximum_size=3145728
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs=Minimal SPIFFS (1.9MB APP with OTA/190KB SPIFFS)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs.build.partitions=min_spiffs
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.min_spiffs.upload.maximum_size=1966080
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.fatflash=16M Flash (2MB APP/12.5MB FAT)
esp32wrover.menu.PartitionScheme.fatflash.build.partitions=ffat

esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qio=QIO
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qio.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qio.build.boot=qio
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dio=DIO
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dio.build.flash_mode=dio
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dio.build.boot=dio
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qout=QOUT
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qout.build.flash_mode=dout
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.qout.build.boot=qout
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dout=DOUT
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dout.build.flash_mode=dout
esp32wrover.menu.FlashMode.dout.build.boot=dout

esp32wrover.menu.FlashFreq.80=80MHz
esp32wrover.menu.FlashFreq.80.build.flash_freq=80m
esp32wrover.menu.FlashFreq.40=40MHz
esp32wrover.menu.FlashFreq.40.build.flash_freq=40m

esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.921600=921600
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.921600.upload.speed=921600
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.115200=115200
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.115200.upload.speed=115200
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.256000.windows=256000
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.256000.upload.speed=256000
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.230400.windows.upload.speed=256000
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.230400=230400
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.230400.upload.speed=230400
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.linux=460800
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.macosx=460800
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.460800.upload.speed=460800
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.512000.windows=512000
esp32wrover.menu.UploadSpeed.512000.upload.speed=512000

esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.none=None
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.none.build.code_debug=0
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.error=Error
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.error.build.code_debug=1
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.warn=Warn
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.warn.build.code_debug=2
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.info=Info
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.info.build.code_debug=3
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.debug=Debug
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.debug.build.code_debug=4
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.verbose=Verbose
esp32wrover.menu.DebugLevel.verbose.build.code_debug=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess you mean the preprocessor defines to distinguish between different boards and include/exclude based on this different code parts.
In ArduinoIDE except from

```
 #ifdef ESP32
 const uint8_t pinA = 12;
 #endif
```

no luck as of core 1.04, because there are no preproc macros defined (like in other architectures).
If you are using PlatformIO you can get the board type from the define ARDUINO_BOARD. 
On ArduinoIDE you only can write your own macros (but this only solves the problem for your dev environment)
So as of core 1.04 you can only do it manually by un/commenting defines:

```
/** Choose the correct model to use and compile the right pin settings*/
#define AI_THINKER_KIT
//#define WROVER_DEV_KIT
//#define ESP_EYE_32
//#define M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define M5STACK_NO_PSRAM
```

As an example the build.board property for SAM Boards is:

```
adafruit_itsybitsy_m0.build.board=ITSYBITSY_M0
```

Then in the Adafruit SAMD Boards platform.txt file you can see where the macro is defined:

```
## Compile c files
recipe.c.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.cmd}" {compiler.c.flags} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.c.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {build.cache_flags} {compiler.arm.cmsis.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

## Compile c++ files
recipe.cpp.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.cpp.cmd}" {compiler.cpp.flags} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.cpp.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {build.cache_flags} {compiler.arm.cmsis.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

## Compile S files
recipe.S.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.S.cmd}" {compiler.S.flags} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.S.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {build.cache_flags} {compiler.arm.cmsis.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
```

If you want to dig intoit deeper: [Arduino 3rd party hardware documantatuion](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/platform-specification/)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want it for.
I will have to do it manually. Thank you for your response

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted